# Depth First Search on Adjacency Matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, depth-first-search, adjacency-matrix

For this program, I am given a set of inputs that I need to store in an adjacency matrix. I've done this, so I have an adjacency matrix Matrix[11][11]. Now, using this matrix, I need to perform a depth first search and return the pi values.

I have the pseudocode for this, so I believe that I need two methods: DFS(graph) and DFS-VISIT(node). However, I'm having trouble actually implementing this. Can I do this using the adjacency matrix directly or do I somehow need to create a graph using the matrix? Any help with actually coding this would be appreciated.

```
DFS(G) 
   for each u ∈ V[G] do 
      color[u] = WHITE  
      ∏[u] = NIL 
   time = 0 
   for each u ∈ V[G] do 
      if color[u] = WHITE then 
         DFS-VISIT(u) 

DFS-VISIT(u) 
   color[u] = GRAY 
   time++ 
   d[u] = time 
   for each v ∈ Adj[u] do 
      if color[v] = WHITE then 
         ∏[v] = u 
         DFS-VISIT(v) 
   color[u] = BLACK
   time++ 
   f[u] = time
```

Comment: It can be done with the adjacency matrix alone. What do you mean by 'pi' values? Please show some part of your code.

Comment: Your graph is the matrix. Please post a simplified version of your DFS(g) function.

Comment: This matrix is representation of your graph, so you don't need to generate another one data structure.

Comment: However, there might be need for some more storage to mark nodes as 'visited' or not; however this depends on the type of graph and the actual application of the algorithm.

Comment: Nodes will be translated by indices of the rows (for instance) and a loop "for each neighbor of node i" will be translated by a loop "for each index j such that mat[i][j] is positive"

Comment: I added the pseudocode that I have for the two functions.

Comment: The pseudocode asks for coloring of nodes to see if they have been visited before; this could be achieved by an array of `bool` of length `n` where `n` is the number of vertices. Furthermore there is an array `∏` which stores the parents in the DFS tree (the node from which a node is visited) and an array `f` to keep track of the sequence in which the nodes are visited.

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo-code you have there seems to assume an adjacency list.

Specifically this code: (indentation corresponding to code blocks assumed)

```
for each v ∈ Adj[u] do 
  if color[v] = white then 
    ∏[v] = u 
    DFS-VISIT(v)
```

The difference is: with an adjacency matrix, all the vertices are there, and one typically uses 0/1 flags to indicate whether there's an edge between the current and target vertices.

So, you should loop through all vertices for that row in the adjacency matrix, and only do something when the flag is set to 1.

That part of the pseudo-code will look something like:

```
for v = 1 to n do  // assuming 1-indexed
  if color[v] = white && AdjMatrix[u][v] == 1 then 
    ∏[v] = u 
    DFS-VISIT(v)
```

As far as I can tell, the rest of the psuedo-code should look identical.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is preferred to code DFS assuming graph to be represented as an adjacency list because the time complexity that results is `O(|V| + |E|)`. But with adjacency matrix the time complexity becomes `O(|V|*|V|)`. Below is an implementation of dfs assuming adjacency matrix representation:

```
#define WHITE 0
#define GRAY 1
#define BLACK 2
int time_;
vector<int> color(n, WHITE), par(n, 0), strt(n, 0), fin(n, 0);
vector<vector<int> > G(n, vector<int>(n, 0));
void dfs_visit(int);
void DFS(){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        color[i] = 0, par[i] = -1;
    time = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < n; i++)
        if(color[j] == WHITE)
            dfs_visit(j);
    }
}
void dfs_visit(int u){
    time_++;
    strt[u] = time_;
    color[u] = GRAY;
    for(int v = 0; v < n && v++)
        if(G[u][v] && color[v] == WHITE){
            par[v] = u;
            dfs_visit(v);
        }
    color[u] = BLACK;
    time_++;
    fin[u] = time_;
}
```

The par[] matrix calculates parent of each vertex and strt[] and fin[] matrices time stamp the vertices. Vertices are 0-based numbered.